# Why Default Constructor and Custom Constructor are called for subclasses of UINavigaionController?

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uikit

```
   @implementation NVController
//Plain Init method
-(id)init
{

    self=[super init];
    if(self)
    {
    }
    return self;
}

//CustomInit Method
-(id)initWithRootViewController:(UIViewController *)rootViewController
{

    self=[super initWithRootViewController:rootViewController];
    if(self)`enter code here`
    {
    }
    return self;
}

@end

NVController *instance=[[NVController alloc] initWithRootViewController:nil];
```

Here In above case ,Since I call only `initWithRootViwController`, another constructor `init` is also called. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If your question was answered, please accept one of the answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens because you did not implement your initializers correctly.

In Objective C there is a concept of *designated initializer*, a single `init` function of your class that all other initializers must call. It is the designated initializer that calls `[super init]` directly; all other initializers need to call `[super init]` indirectly by invoking the designated initializer.

In your particular case you need to move the code common to both your `init` and `initWithRootViewController:`, if any, into the `initWithRootViewController:` initializer, and rewrite the plain `init` as follows:

```
-(id)init {
    return [self initWithRootViewController:nil];
}
```

** EDIT :** (in response to the comment indicating that this solution causes an infinite recursion) I think the reason why you get infinite recursion has to do specifically with implementation details of `UINavigationController`, which should not be inherited. According to Apple's documentation,

> The `UINavigationController` class implements a specialized view controller that manages the navigation of hierarchical content. This class is not intended for subclassing. Instead, you use instances of it as-is in situations where you want your application’s user interface to reflect the hierarchical nature of your content.

**EDIT**: The prohibition against subclassing has been lifted in iOS 6 - see the documentation for UINavigationController.

Comment: `@implementation NVController
//Plain Init method
-(id)init
{
       return [self initWithRootViewController:nil];
}

//CustomInit Method
-(id)initWithRootViewController:(UIViewController *)rootViewController
{
    self=[super initWithRootViewController:rootViewController];
    if(self)
    {
    }
    return self;
}
@end
`
Here it leads to infinite loop

Comment: @Allamaprabhu are you inheriting `UINavigationController`?

Comment: @Allamaprabhu Set a breakpoint in the `init` method of your class, and see what is calling it back. `UINavigationController` shouldn't call your `init`, unless there is one of your classes in the middle that performs the call.

Comment: **Here Is the stack Trace**    
    (lldb) bt      
    * thread #1: tid = 0x1f03, 0x000022ae Sample`-[NVController init] + 30 at NVController.m:15, stop reason = step over </br>   
    frame #0: 0x000022ae Sample`-[NVController init] + 30 at NVController.m:15//My class initilizer again-(id)init  .Why this?? <br/>   
frame #1: 0x000e595f UIKit`-[UINavigationController initWithRootViewController:] + 35//Super class initilizer    
    frame #2: 0x0000232b Sample`-[NVController initWithRootViewController:] + 75 at NVController.m:21//My class initilizer    
    frame #3: 0x00001e67

Comment: @Allamaprabhu I think the issue is specific to `UINavigationController` - Apple says that you should not be subclassing it.

Comment: :Thank you very much for ur interest in it.Even i read from apple dev doc that One should not inherit UINavigationController Class.
But the thing still haunting me is how init method of derived class can be called from  super class?
When i went across stack trace i found that,First My class initWihtRootViewController is called then super class initWihtRootViewController then init of my class is called...Any thoughts on this?

Comment: @Allamaprabhu I guess the `initWithRootViewController:` constructor of the superclass calls in to `[self init]` instead of `[super init]`, bringing it straight into your implementation. I'd be curious to take a look at Apple's sources, if they were open, to see if my guess is right.

Comment: :LOL(Apple and OpenSource)...Exactly,I think u r right...they are calling [self init] ,instead of [super init];

Answer (score 2):

I guess `initWithRootViewController:` is implemented like this:

```
-(id)initWithRootViewController:(UIViewController *)rootViewController
{
    self=[self init];
    if(self)
    {
        // do something with rootViewController
    }
    return self;
}
```

Comment: Nope..I am pretty sure about that,I am not calling
 
self=[super init];

Instead I calling


self=[super initWithRootViewController:rootViewController];

Comment: Where in my answer did I say you called `[super init]`? The **superclass's** implementation of `initWithRootViewController` calls `[self init]`

Comment: lol! Thanks :) If you like my answer, you can vote for it (or accept it)